# If and Else statements in c not working

Tags: c, gcc, raspberry-pi

I have made this little test program in c on my raspberry pi model b.

It compiles without errors, however, the if statement never works:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    char *test = 0;
    printf("Alpha or Beta\n");
    scanf(" %s", test);
    if (test == "Alpha")
    {
        printf("This is string one test\n");
        printf("This is string two test\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("An error has occured\n");    
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For example:
I will type Alpha and it will always give me the error has occurred message.

Comment: Shouldn't `" %s"` be `"%s"`? Without the space?

Comment: Besides the wrong string comparison, you are writing to an uninitialized pointer, `test`.

Comment: You should also, check `scanf()`'s return value.

Comment: The pointer was defined as char *test = 0;

Comment: FWIW, a NULL (`0`, here)is also _considered_ invalid pointer to write to.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I tried that and it said that I had a segmentation fault

Comment: who asked you to try writing into invalid pointer? allocate memory using `malloc()`, maybe? also, `free()` afterwards. or else, cut the crap, go for a simple array. I don't see any reason to use dynamic allocation here.

Comment: refactored your code.You can check it here.use strcmp to compare strings.http://ideone.com/dbGeEy

Comment: @SouravGhosh No, I mean I changed the value from 0 and it gave me a segmentation fault

Comment: and how did you _change_ exactly?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I changed it to;

Comment: @SouravGhosh Sorry, I accidentally clicked enter. I changed it to:         char test[10];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare strings using "==".  Use the strcmp function instead.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp

Comment: Even when I use numbers (I also changed it to int, and did all of the %d and &test and stuff like that), and it still doesn't work for me.

Comment: That's because your pointers (which is what you're checking) will not be the same since they are pointing to different memory addresses.  I promise you that if/else works just fine.

Comment: @roost0031 would this be ok? char test[10]

Comment: Yes, but you have to make sure to still use strcmp() and not "==".  Also, don't forget to null terminate your string.

Comment: Could you add a new answer with that code fixed? (If it is too much trouble I understand)

Comment: Why don't you give it a shot?  It's your homework.  You won't learn anything if I just do it for you.  If you run into trouble, then ask for help.  It's pretty inappropriate to ask StackOverflow to do stuff for you and you will get downvoted mercelessly.

Comment: Sorry, ok. (I haven't been here much). Could you please explain how comparing strings would fix my problem?

Comment: Because currently, the if/else will always select the else path and will always print "error has occurred".  If you use the function as suggested, it should take the "if" path.